# Calling "bind"-ed input from server.R

Tags: r, shiny, inputbinding

I successfully implemented the binding capability of Shiny, but the function is defined in ui.R and any calls from server.R of this new input result in a function not found error.

I am passing `session` to server.R (not sure if that makes a difference) and I also created a global.R that simply has the function in it (not sure if I need anything beyond that, because that doesn't even let me call the function in ui.R).

How can I call a custom shiny input function from server.R (specifically in a `renderUI`)?

Example code here: (the call to `sortList` works fine from ui.R but not server.R)
https://gist.github.com/jpd527/9687359

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking, but it sounds like you're trying to do something Shiny doesn't do. Can you post some code and maybe we can provide a more helpful answer?

Comment: Added code. I'm certain this is something Shiny has the capability to do, I'm just not sure what additional steps I need to take.

Comment: Thanks, much more clear! That's definitely possible.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for but I have a binding for sortable lists here https://github.com/mostly-harmless/sortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a patched Gist: https://gist.github.com/trestletech/9691459

There are two major [changes](https://gist.github.com/trestletech/9691459/revisions) here:

1. I moved the `sortListInput` function to `global.R`. You mention you'd tried that, but it worked swimmingly to expose the function to both `server` and `UI`.
2. The next issue was that you were only initializing the `sortListInput` at page creation. You had `$( ".sortableList" ).sortable(); $( ".sortableList" ).disableSelection();` in a singleton `<script>` in your `<head>`, but that's only going to run once at page creation. So dynamically created `sortableLists` that get created later would never be initialized. So I added a `<script>` chunk to your `sortListInput` that will run that code every time you generate a new one. I'm unaware of a cleaner way to do this right now, but perhaps one does/will exist...

A couple of things to be aware of:

- Since you're now initializing all `sortListInputs` each time one gets dynamically created, you need to be sure that that init code is idempotent -- i.e. you're not going to break existing ones when you run that code.
- I noticed that you're loading your own version of jQuery and some other jQuery libraries. Be careful about that since Shiny also has a version of jQuery it depends on. You'll need to be sure there aren't any conflicts.

Comment: Super helpful across the board. I also discovered that while refreshing the page will update changes to server, ui and global, if the global file didn't exist when the shiny app was started, it won't look for it. Reran the app and it's working with global now.